# What does mongoose.connection do in node?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

What does mongoose.connection do and return ?
I'm new in mongoose.
I'll find this one in some tutorial but nobody tells what actually occurs behind the scene.

```
var db = mongoose.connection;
```

Is it return already created instance of database, or new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an instance of `EventEmitter` class

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose");
const EventEmitter = require('events');

var db = mongoose.connection;

console.log(db instanceof EventEmitter); // true
```

as you can listen for events like below

```
db.on('error', err => {
  logError(err);
});
```

See [here](https://repl.it/join/chmvuxrx-shubhamdixit863)

See [Events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_events)

Answer (score 0):

> Mongoose creates a default connection when you call
> mongoose.connect(). You can access the default connection using
> mongoose.connection.

This is the snippet from the [official documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html) so yes, it does return the already established connection to the database (considering that you have already called `mongoose.connect` somewhere else before it).

Moreover, you can also get the events emitted (errors etc) by listening to `mongoose.connection`.